# python dbf max query

Tags: python, dbf

I'm using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) library for reading dbf files in python. How can I get a MAX value of a column. I want the following sql

`SELECT MAX(DATE_OPEN) FROM MYFILE.DBF`

Comment: The SQL query is correct. What's the problem? What's the error message?

Comment: @Oleg: The problem is the library doesn't support sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dbf library doesn't support full sql (in fact, I renamed the existing functionality to `pql` to emphasize that), you'll have to write your own `max` routine.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
def field_max(table, field):
    """
    return the maximum value for column `field` in table

    table should be a collection of records or an open table
    field should be a field name (either `str` or `unicode`)
    """
    return max([rec[field] for rec in table])
```